Use dask with numactl
I am using dask to parallelize an operation that is memory-bound. So, I want to ensure each dask worker has access to a single NUMA node and prevent cross-node memory access. I can do this in the command-line with something like
numactl --physcpubind=0-63 --membind=0-0 dask-worker
numactl --physcpubind=64-127 --membind=0-1 dask-worker

However, I am instantiating the dask cluster via dask.distributed.LocalCluster. Is there a way to do the equivalent of the above in the python API? I have looked through the documentation, and haven't seen much that helps. ChatGPT suggest making a custom Worker class and overriding the start method, but then hallucinates attributes that don't exist in that class.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is. Di you observe a strong difference with or without binding to a NUMA node?

For my use-case, there is about a 1.5x to 2x speedup when I bind to a NUMA node. I ended up writing a function that uses subprocess.run to run the dask scheduler and dask worker commands as above. But that follows the "manual setup" that the dask documentation discourages.

As Guillaume EB mentioned, it does not seem possible from the LocalCluster interface. However, I managed to put together a function that uses subprocess to setup a dask cluster from Python. For anyone else coming to this question, here is what I have that can be a starting point for you
import json
import os
import subprocess
import time
from pathlib import Path

from dask.distributed import Client


def setup_numa_aware_cluster(
    num_workers: int = 8,
    threads_per_worker: int = 4,
    scheduler_port: str | None = None,
    logfile_directory: str | Path = "/tmp",
) -> Client:
    """Setup a NUMA-aware dask cluster on a single TACC node"""
    # Make scheduler file based on time
    scheduler_file_directory = Path(logfile_directory) / "scheduler_files"
    scheduler_file_directory.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    timestamp = int(time.time())
    filename = scheduler_file_directory / f"slurm_strategy_scheduler_t{timestamp}.json"

    # Make logfiles that the scheduler and workers will go to based on the same
    logfile_directory = Path(logfile_directory) / "dask_logfiles" / f"t{timestamp}"
    logfile_directory.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
    scheduler_logfile = open(logfile_directory / "scheduler_logs.txt", "w+")
    workers_logfile = open(logfile_directory / "worker_logs.txt", "w+")

    # Kick off the scheduler and wait for the file to appear
    scheduler_args = [
        "dask",
        "scheduler",
        "--scheduler-file",
        str(filename),
    ]
    if scheduler_port is not None:
        scheduler_args.extend(["--port", str(scheduler_port)])
    scheduler_process = subprocess.Popen(
        scheduler_args,
        stderr=scheduler_logfile,
    )
    while not filename.exists():
        return_code = scheduler_process.poll()
        if return_code is not None and return_code != 0:
            scheduler_logfile.seek(0)
            raise OSError(scheduler_logfile.read())
        time.sleep(1)
    with open(filename, "r") as scheduler_file:
        scheduler_meta = json.load(scheduler_file)

    # Figure out numa node setup for this compute node
    numa_nodes = parse_numa_hardware()
    num_numa_nodes = len(numa_nodes)

    # Kick off workers. This assumes each numa node has the same number of cores
    workers_per_set = [num_workers // num_numa_nodes] * num_numa_nodes
    total_workers = sum(workers_per_set)
    if total_workers != num_workers:
        # The number of workers is not evenly divisible by number of numa nodes
        # So, just assign the extra workers to the last numa node
        difference = num_workers - total_workers
        workers_per_set[-1] += difference
    for i, number_of_workers in enumerate(workers_per_set):
        cpus = ",".join([str(c) for c in numa_nodes[i]])
        cmd_parts = [
            "numactl",
            f"--physcpubind={cpus}",
            f"--membind={i}-{i}",
            "dask",
            "worker",
            "--scheduler-file",
            str(filename),
            "--nthreads",
            str(threads_per_worker),
            "--nworkers",
            str(number_of_workers),
        ]
        print(f"Creating workers using\n\n{' '.join(cmd_parts)}")
        worker_creation = subprocess.Popen(
            cmd_parts,
            stderr=workers_logfile,
        )

    # Create a client
    client = Client(address=scheduler_meta["address"])

    # Wait for the workers to boot up
    while True:
        workers = client.scheduler_info().get("workers", [])
        if len(workers) == num_workers:
            break
        time.sleep(1)

    return client


def parse_numa_hardware() -> list[list[int]]:

    # Figure out numa node setup for this compute node
    result = subprocess.run(["numactl", "--hardware"], capture_output=True)
    numa_nodes = []
    for line in result.stdout.decode().split("\n"):
        if line.startswith("node") and "cpus: " in line:
            numa_nodes.append([int(n) for n in line.partition("cpus:")[2].split()])
    return numa_nodes

